# Dashed Circular Bar with Percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a circular progress bar with dashed line. I programmatically create `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to draw a circle with percentage.

Instead of solid circle, I need to draw dashed circle which looks like this:

[image: dashed line]

I couldn't change solid circle to dashed one. Am I missing something or do I need to change my logic to draw dashed circle?

https://jsfiddle.net/6mu97jyL/

```js
class CircularProgressBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    // Size of the enclosing square
    const sqSize = this.props.sqSize;
    // SVG centers the stroke width on the radius, subtract out so circle fits in square
    const radius = (this.props.sqSize - this.props.strokeWidth) / 2;
    // Enclose cicle in a circumscribing square
    const viewBox = `0 0 ${sqSize} ${sqSize}`;
    // Arc length at 100% coverage is the circle circumference
    const dashArray = radius * Math.PI * 2;
    // Scale 100% coverage overlay with the actual percent
    const dashOffset = dashArray - dashArray * this.props.percentage / 100;

    return (
      <svg
          width={this.props.sqSize}
          height={this.props.sqSize}
          viewBox={viewBox}>
          <circle
            className="circle-background"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`} />
          <circle
            className="circle-progress"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`}
            transform={`rotate(-90 ${this.props.sqSize / 2} ${this.props.sqSize / 2})`}
            style={{
              strokeDasharray: dashArray,
              strokeDashoffset: dashOffset
            }} />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

CircularProgressBar.defaultProps = {
  sqSize: 200,
  percentage: 25,
  strokeWidth: 10
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      percentage: 25
    };

    this.handleChangeEvent = this.handleChangeEvent.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeEvent(event) {
    this.setState({
      percentage: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <CircularProgressBar
            strokeWidth="10"
            sqSize="200"
            percentage={this.state.percentage}/>
          <div>
            <input 
              id="progressInput" 
              type="range" 
              min="0" 
              max="100" 
              step="1"
              value={this.state.percentage}
              onChange={this.handleChangeEvent}/>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#app {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#progressInput {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.circle-background,
.circle-progress {
  fill: none;
}

.circle-background {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.circle-progress {
  stroke: #F99123;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center" id="app">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not behind an external link.

Comment: @Colin, it shows a weird error. That's why I wanted to put an external link.

Comment: @Eniss, fixed the snippet error. You forgot to activate the es5 syntax in the snippet. Wait until the edit is accepted

Comment: @mthrsj Thank you. You are awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is somewhat in the range of what you are looking for. 
 ( full snippet / demo below)

Im not an expert on this subject, so there might be another option (like two half circles with different styling) - but what is basically done here is to lay another circle on top of the solid circle, and make sure it has the same stroke color as the page. This will then mask over gaps of the circle behind, (basically hide parts of the circle).

```js
          <circle
            className="circle-dashes"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`}
            style={{
              strokeDasharray: "5 10" // Adjust the spacing here
            }} />
```

css:

```css
.circle-dashes {
  stroke: #FFF;
  fill: none;
}
```

and remove

```
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
```

A few minor tweaks to fit your need, and hopefully you got it!

[image: Preview of result]

If you take a look at the app with another background color, the changes might be more obvious.

[image: With dark background]

```js
class CircularProgressBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    // Size of the enclosing square
    const sqSize = this.props.sqSize;
    // SVG centers the stroke width on the radius, subtract out so circle fits in square
    const radius = (this.props.sqSize - this.props.strokeWidth) / 2;
    // Enclose cicle in a circumscribing square
    const viewBox = `0 0 ${sqSize} ${sqSize}`;
    // Arc length at 100% coverage is the circle circumference
    const dashArray = radius * Math.PI * 2;
    // Scale 100% coverage overlay with the actual percent
    const dashOffset = dashArray - dashArray * this.props.percentage / 100;

    return (
      <svg
          width={this.props.sqSize}
          height={this.props.sqSize}
          viewBox={viewBox}>
          <circle
            className="circle-background"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`} />
          <circle
            className="circle-progress"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`}
            // Start progress marker at 12 O'Clock
            transform={`rotate(-90 ${this.props.sqSize / 2} ${this.props.sqSize / 2})`}
            style={{
              strokeDasharray: dashArray,
              strokeDashoffset: dashOffset
            }} />
            
            <circle
            className="circle-dashes"
            cx={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            cy={this.props.sqSize / 2}
            r={radius}
            strokeWidth={`${this.props.strokeWidth}px`}
            style={{
              strokeDasharray: "5 10"
            }} />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

CircularProgressBar.defaultProps = {
  sqSize: 200,
  percentage: 25,
  strokeWidth: 10
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      percentage: 25
    };

    this.handleChangeEvent = this.handleChangeEvent.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeEvent(event) {
    this.setState({
      percentage: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <CircularProgressBar
            strokeWidth="10"
            sqSize="200"
            percentage={this.state.percentage}/>
          <div>
            <input 
              id="progressInput" 
              type="range" 
              min="0" 
              max="100" 
              step="1"
              value={this.state.percentage}
              onChange={this.handleChangeEvent}/>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
#app {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#progressInput {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 30%;
}

.circle-background,
.circle-progress {
  fill: none;
}

.circle-background {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.circle-dashes {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: none;
}

.circle-progress {
  stroke: #F99123;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center" id="app">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is close to what I do need. Can we make background(the gray one) solid? So only orange color will be dashed.

Comment: Change the css of the `.circle-dashes` and make the stroke color `#ddd´ to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)