# Is it possible to use an oval ShapeDrawable as a ProgressBarDrawable with behaviour similar to a ring ShapeDrawable?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm in the process of developing a compound view that I'm trying to get to look like the following image. I've marked (with a red arrow) the part that I'm having trouble with):

[image: Desired UI]

However, at present I'm unable to get the arc to cleanly start and finish (as shown below):

[image: Current UI]

My code for this inner (dashed) progress drawable is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <clip>
                <shape
                    android:shape="oval"
                    android:useLevel="true">

                    <size
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:height="60dp" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="13dp"
                        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:dashWidth="3dp"
                        android:dashGap="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <clip>
                <shape
                    android:shape="oval"
                    android:useLevel="true">

                    <size
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:height="60dp" />

                    <stroke
                        android:width="13dp"
                        android:color="@android:color/white"
                        android:dashWidth="3dp"
                        android:dashGap="5dp" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The surrounding progress drawables that I've made work fine with `android:shape="ring"` and removing the `<clip>` tags, but I can't seem to get the same clean clockwise progress behaviour using an `android:shape="oval"`.

In case it helps, my code for setting the drawable to my `ProgressBar` is as follows:

```xml
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_dashed_gauge"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:scaleX="0.75"
    android:scaleY="0.75"
    android:progress="80"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/dashed_gauge"
    android:secondaryProgress="80"
    />
```

Any help with getting this dashed `ProgressBar` to show progress in a manner similar to my other `ProgressBar` views would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: [link1](https://cocoapods.org/pods/UICircularProgressRing)    [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455050/dashed-circular-bar-with-percentage)   Maybe this links can help you with it.

Comment: @SarthakJoshi both of your links are not related to Android/Java and do not come close to helping with my question at all. There are plenty of actual Android libraries that are capable of making great looking circular progress bars, but none I’ve seen are capable of the behaviour that I’ve indicated in my question.